# Normal Map Only Baking To Grey or Blue

Tags: uv, normals

So, I did everything from the tutorials right, I also removed doubles and took away all previous textures and materials and did all of the things right. But, how come the Normal map is still grey. If I turn off Select to Active, it becomes blue... I read litterally all of the problems, but never found this one. I also re-sized the meshes and played around with bias but nothing happened.

Link to .blend file [The Problem File of DOOOOOOMMMMM!!!!!](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7bU7_85XLwLY1ViTk1IN24zVnc/edit?usp=sharing)

[image: The Picture of Doom]

Comment: Is it possible you could upload your .blend?

Comment: umm... okay....

Comment: Hm.. that's odd, it [worked for me](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4RQtm.png).. All I did was move the high-res version to the same location as the low-res version.

Comment: ... oh. Also, why do people only use the comment section now, not the answer section?

Comment: I don't like to answer if I don't have a complete answer..